# How can I make the listings package break one word into multiple lines?

Tags: listings, line-breaking, xml

The following code does not break even though the breaklines and breakatwhitespace is set:

```
\lstset{
  language=XML,
  numbers=left,        
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  stepnumber=1,                   
  numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},      % choose the background color. You must
  showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding
  showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces
  showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings
  frame=single,                   % adds a frame
  rulecolor=\color{black},        % if not set, the frame-color
  tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen
  title=\lstname,                   % show the filename of files
                                  % also try caption instead of title
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},          % keyword style
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},       % comment style stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breakautoindent=true
          % string literal style
}

\lstset{caption={Results of the example},label=lst:results}
\begin{lstlisting}
  <message>
    <value>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</value>
  </message>
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image: result of the code above]

Any ideas what I can set in order to make it break automatically on the value part?

Comment: @user202729 That’s a great suggestion. Done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As described in your question the package `listings` can automatically break long lines. The is limited. The package breaks only on characters which are defined as `others`. To allow the break at every point you must say `listings` that a letter isn't a letter. This can be done be redefining the following definition:

Original:

```
\def\lst@lettertrue{\let\lst@ifletter\iftrue}
```

Redefinition

```
\def\lst@lettertrue{\let\lst@ifletter\iffalse}
```

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
}
\makeatletter
\def\lst@lettertrue{\let\lst@ifletter\iffalse}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Results of the example},label=lst:results,]
  <message>
    <value>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</value>
  </message>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

To highlight the automatic line breaks you can work with the options `postbreak` and `prebreak`.

[image]

Comment: This solution disables the possibility to highlight words by color. Try `language=XML, morekeywords={value}, keywordstyle=\color{blue},` with and without `\def\lst@lettertrue{\let\lst@ifletter\iffalse}`! Any idea how to avoid this clash?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi In `listings`, for an identifier to get highlighted, all  of the chars it contains must be "letters". There's no way around that.

Comment: There's a way around that but it involves define a new syntax highlighting [How to get listings that both feature line breaking of long identifiers and keywords highlighting? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125040/how-to-get-listings-that-both-feature-line-breaking-of-long-identifiers-and-keyw?noredirect=1&lq=1)