# Listings package does not break with mwrep document class

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I cannot get listings package to break lines with any of the methods described in previous questions:
[Listings package does not break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65743/listings-package-does-not-break), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981020/how-to-force-line-wrapping-in-listings-package

This problem appears only when using `mwrep` document class. In `report` or `article` line-breaks work just fine.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[ breaklines=true ]
Some text with a long line that needs to be broken but is not with mwrep documentclass. What should I do about it?
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I identified that the culprit is `mwrep` document class and the fact that it sets `\exhyphenpenalty=10000` in its source, which interferes with listings package ability to break lines.

The solution I found is changing it back to 100 before the listing and restoring the changed value at the end of the listing:

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\exhyphenpenalty=100}
\AfterEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\exhyphenpenalty=10000}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[ breaklines=true ]
Some text with a long line that needs to be broken but is not with mwrep documentclass. What should I do about it?
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[Source of the solution (in Polish)](http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/84/32020/)

Comment: You can use the advantages of `etoolbox` to set `\exhyphenpenalty` at the beginning of each environment.

Comment: Good point, I'll modify my solution.

Comment: Your example *only* seems to work if the code line starting with `\AtEndEnvironment` is dropped.

Comment: OK, it seems the right hook to use is `\AfterEndEnvironment` then.