# Listings not breaking up

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I have a code listing as shown in the picture (number 4) that goes a bit out of the margin although   breaklines=true. When I try to break new line it gives me an error `Listings Error: lstinline ended by EOL.` How can I break this up so that the arguments line up in a more elegant way like:

```
 computeInitialValues(const Query& query,
                      const std::vector<const Array*> &objects,
                      std::vector< std::vector<unsigned char>> &values,
                      bool &hasSolution)
```

[image]

EDIT: Code sample:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx, tikz, enumerate, amssymb, pgf}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{bchart}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\lstset{
%frame=tb,
   language=C++,
   aboveskip=3mm,
   belowskip=3mm,
   showstringspaces=false,
   columns=flexible,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\bfseries,
   numbers=none,
   numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
   commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
   breaklines=true,
   breakatwhitespace=true,
   tabsize=3
}
\begin{document}

\lstinline$bool computeInitialValues(const Query& query, const vector<const Array*>& objects, vector<vector<unsigned char>>& values, bool& hasSolution )$ computes the initial values for a list of objects.   

\end{document}
```

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65743/listings-package-does-not-break/65839#65839

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I tried but it doesn't work unfortunately =/

Comment: Use `\sloppy` to allow breaks

Comment: Thanks @MarcoDaniel it worked. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it. Also, thanks everyone for taking their time to help as well.

Comment: @Cemre: Done. Hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TeX FAQ describes your behavior in the article [*(La)TeX makes overfull lines*](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-overfull)

In your case the command `\sloppy` helps. To avoid `\tolerance9999` for the whole document you must set `\sloppy` local.

Please note the following sentence from the FAQ:

> `\sloppy` ... can allow pretty poor-looking breaks

Here an real minimal example without non-related packages:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,breaklines=true}
\begin{document}
{\sloppy\lstinline$bool computeInitialValues(const Query& query, const vector<const Array*>& objects, vector<vector<unsigned char>>& values, bool& hasSolution )$} computes the initial values for a list of objects.   

\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case there does not appear to be any different in the output with or without `\sloppy`.  I am not sure, but think it has to do with there not being an end of paragraph within which `\sloppy` is to apply as the output it better if you move the `\sloppy` _outside_ of the brace group.

Comment: @PeterGrill: If I put `\sloppy` outside the group it won't work local.

Comment: Yes I agree. But the MWE you provided does not show any difference with, or without the addition of `\sloppy`.  Now that  I re-read it, my earlier comment does not seem very clear. What I meant was that applying `\sloppy` outside of the brace group does show that it works in this MWE. It works inside only if there is another paragraph. So applying something like `\endgraf` at the end makes it work. But perhaps there is a better way to do this that I am not aware of.

Comment: @PeterGrill local \sloppy didn't work at first (it only worked if it wasn't local) as you said but than I extended the range of braces a bit which made it work but I am not sure why