# Listing linebreaking not working

Tags: listings, line-breaking

got a listing where the code include a very long sequence of characters (letters, numbers & other).
With `linebreak=true`, the sequence gets broken at non-letter characters.
However I still got a very long sequence of letters, that's not getting breaking down.
With all other options, see code, the result is still the same.

```
\lstinputlisting[language=XML, breaklines=true, breakindent=0pt, breakautoindent=true, linewidth=\textwidth, breakatwhitespace=false,  caption=Respons.]{outlook/Vinden_kalender_item_antwoord.xml}
```

Working in writelatex.com.

vinden_kal ..., the problem is the t:ItemId  tag
At the + and /, the line gets broken down.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       This syntax file is intended for students of the        %
%       FIIW writing their master thesis.               %
%       We hope they can use it as a helping hand in writing        %
%       their thesis.                           %
%                                       %
%       Syntax originally written by Filip Van Rysselberghe     %
%       Adapted for KaHo St. Lieven by Bart Blanckaert          %
%                                       %
%       Modified by Koen Vangheluwe based on PhD stylefile of RUG   %
%                                       %
%       Adapted for FIIW by Jannes Verstichel               %
%       Last modified: 12/11/2013 v1.0                  %
%                                       %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

%%%%fiiw_gent
\makeatletter

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{textpos}

% \usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif


% fancyheadings
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\scriptsize\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\scriptsize\bfseries\sffamily\leftmark}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\scriptsize\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

% Koen Vangheluwe 29/05/2009: toegevoegd om "\headheight is too small" warning te voorkomen
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

% Koen Vangheluwe 16/03/2010: toegevoegd wegens voor witte pagina's met empty style bij het gebruik van twoside en report
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
  \hbox{}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \newpage
  \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% We'll head off with the definitions of the new commands %
%   as promotor, copromotor, etc              %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\subtitle#1{\gdef\@subtitle{#1}}
\def\promotorA[#1]#2{\gdef\@promotorAtype{#1}\gdef\@promotorAname{#2}}
\def\promotorB[#1]#2{\gdef\@promotorBtype{#1}\gdef\@promotorBname{#2}}
\def\promotorC[#1]#2{\gdef\@promotorCtype{#1}\gdef\@promotorCname{#2}}
\def\opleiding#1{\gdef\@opleiding{#1}}
\def\afdeling#1{\gdef\@afdeling{#1}}
\def\academicyear#1{\gdef\@academicyear{#1}}
\def\forename#1{\gdef\@forename{#1}}
\def\surname#1{\gdef\@surname{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   Secondly we declare and fill in the newly created variables %
% Sometimes we use standard definitions as is the case for      %
%   the titles.                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\@title{Titel Masterproef}
\def\@subtitle{Ondertitel (factultatief)}
\def\@forename{Voornaam}
\def\@surname{Achternaam}
\def\@opleiding{naam van de opleiding}
\def\@afdeling{afstudeerrichting}
\def\@promotorAname{} 
\def\@promotorBname{}
\def\@promotorCname{}
\def\@promotorAtype{} 
\def\@promotorBtype{}
\def\@promotorCtype{}
\def\@academicyear{}

% We also define some new if-structures to check whether you
% want to add a specific page in your thesis\bfseries\sffamily\rightmark
\newif\iflistoffigurespage
\newif\iflistoftablespage
\newif\iflistofsymbolspage
\newif\ifacknowledgementspage
\newif\ifabstractpage

\listoffigurespagefalse
\listoftablespagefalse

\listofsymbolspagefalse
\def\listofsymbols#1{\gdef\@listofsymbolsfile{\input{#1}}}

\acknowledgementspagefalse
\def\acknowledgements#1{\gdef\@acknowledgementsfile{\input{#1}}}

\abstractpagefalse
\def\abstracts#1{\gdef\@abstractfile{\input{#1}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   This function formats the titlepage using the   %
%   variables set before.                       %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Define the color of the title
\definecolor{titlegreen}{RGB}{39,142,116}
\def\titlep{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
    \begin{picture}(0,0)(0,26)
    \hspace{-10em}\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{cover_fiiw_gent.pdf}
    \end{picture}
    \vskip1in
    \vfill
    \begingroup
      \fontsize{40pt}{12pt}\selectfont
        \textcolor{titlegreen}{{\textsf{\@title}}} \\\\
    \endgroup
    {\LARGE\textsf{\@subtitle}}
    \vfill
    \begin{flushright}
        \textsf{\LARGE\textbf{\@forename~\MakeUppercase{\@surname}}}
    \end{flushright}
    \vspace{10em}
    \begin{Parallel}{0.48\textwidth}{0.48\textwidth}
        \ParallelLText{\noindent
            \begin{list}{label}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{10em}\setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}\setlength{\labelwidth}{9.5em}\setlength{\itemsep}{-.5ex}}
                \ifx \@promotorAname \@empty
                \else
                    \item[\@promotorAtype:\hfill] \@promotorAname
                \fi
                \ifx \@promotorBname \@empty
                \else
                    \item[\@promotorBtype:\hfill] \@promotorBname
                \fi
                \ifx \@promotorCname \@empty
                \else 
                    \item[\@promotorCtype:\hfill] \@promotorCname
                \fi
            \end{list}
        }
        \ParallelRText{\noindent \vspace{1em}
            \begin{flushright}
                Masterproef ingediend tot het behalen van \\
                de graad van master in de industri\"ele \\
                wetenschappen: \@opleiding \\
                \@afdeling
            \end{flushright}
        }
    \end{Parallel}
%   \vspace{3em}
    \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
    \setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
    \begin{textblock}{5}(5.5,1.5)
            Academiejaar \@academicyear
    \end{textblock}
    \cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \null
    \vfill
    %{\LARGE{Opgelet! Het copyright moet nog aangepast worden!}}\\\\
    \copyright Copyright KU Leuven \\\\
    Zonder voorafgaande schriftelijke toestemming van zowel de promotor(en) als de auteur(s) is overnemen, kopi\"eren, gebruiken of realiseren van deze uitgave of gedeelten ervan verboden. Voor aanvragen tot of informatie i.v.m.~het overnemen en/of gebruik en/of realisatie van gedeelten uit deze publicatie, wend u tot KU Leuven campus Gent, Gebroeders De Smetstraat 1, B-9000 Gent, +32-9-2658610 of via e-mail iiw.kaho.gent@kuleuven.be. \\\\
    Voorafgaande schriftelijke toestemming van de promotor(en) is eveneens vereist voor het aanwenden van de in deze masterproef beschreven (originele) methoden, producten, schakelingen en programma's voor industrieel of commercieel nut en voor de inzending van deze publicatie ter deelname aan wetenschappelijke prijzen of wedstrijden.
    \cleardoublepage
}

% Indentation
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.25ex}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{12pt plus 3pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{12pt plus 3pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{12pt plus 3pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{12pt plus 3pt}

\parskip 1mm

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%&&&&&&&&&&&%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% BeforePreface adds the titlepage and when you                  %
% turned on the acknowledgements page, it will be generated too  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\preface{
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \titlep        

    \ifacknowledgementspage 
        \chapter*{Dankwoord} \@acknowledgementsfile
    \fi

    \ifabstractpage 
        \chapter*{Abstract} \@abstractfile
    \fi

    \tableofcontents

    \iflistoffigurespage
        \listoffigures
    \fi

    \iflistoftablespage
        \listoftables
    \fi

    \iflistofsymbolspage
        %\chapter*{Lijst van symbolen}
        \@listofsymbolsfile
    \fi

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
}

% Start with pagestyle{headings} in case front matter isn't processed
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\makeatother

%%%%%%% doc itself

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
% Indien je je thesis recto-verso wil afdrukken gebruik je onderstaande opties i.p.v. bovenstaande
%\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margins]{trackchanges}
\addeditor{Eline}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
% om niet ascii karakters rechtstreeks te kunnen inputten
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}            % commentarieer deze regel uit als je utf8 encoded files gebruikt in plaats van latin1
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}                        % URL's invoegen in tekst met behulp van \url{http://}
\usepackage[small,bf,hang]{caption}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
\chapterfont{\raggedleft\sffamily}

\usepackage{float}                      % De optie H voor de plaatsing van figuren op de plaats waar je ze invoegt. bvb. \begin{figure}[H]
%\usepackage{longtable}                 % tabellen die over meerdere pagina's gespreid worden
%\usepackage[times]{quotchap}           % indien je fancy hoofdstuktitels wil
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
%\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{fiiw_gent}
\usepackage{rotating}

%door onderstaande regels in commentaar te zetten, of op false, kan je pagina's weglaten
%bijvoorbeeld het weglaten van een voorwoord, lijst met symbolen, ...
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%voorwoord toevoegen?
\acknowledgementspagetrue
\acknowledgements{voorwoord}            %.tex file met daarin het voorwoord
%abstract toevoegen?
\abstractpagetrue
\abstracts{abstract}                    %.tex file met daarin het abstract
%lijst van figuren toevoegen?
\listoffigurespagetrue
%lijst van tabellen toevoegen?
%\listoftablespagetrue
%lijst van symbolen toevoegen?
%\listofsymbolspagetrue
%\listofsymbols{symbolen}               %.tex file met daarin de lijst van symbolen



\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[language=XML, breaklines=true, breakindent=0pt, breakautoindent=true, linewidth=\textwidth, breakatwhitespace=false,  caption=Respons van het gevonden kalender item.]{outlook/Vinden_kalender_item_antwoord.xml}

\end{document}


%%%%%%% Vinden_kalender_item_antwoord.xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
      <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="14" MinorVersion="2" MajorBuildNumber="387" MinorBuildNumber="0" Version="Exchange2010_SP2" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <m:FindItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
         <m:ResponseMessages>
            <m:FindItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
               <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
               <m:RootFolder TotalItemsInView="1" IncludesLastItemInRange="true">
                  <t:Items>
                     <t:CalendarItem>
                        <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGQ4ZWQ5ZDAyLTMzNmMtNGEwZC1iZWQ4LTEyMzVkNDhhOTgzMwBGAAAAAAClRU98ditGSbuQMxW+bNQEBwD3K7SN9dTDQr6wC4Bve/iXAAAAj+XHAAD3K7SN9dTDQr6wC4Bve/iXAAAAkoSvAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAAD3K7SN9dTDQr6wC4Bve/iXAAAAkqS3"/>
                     </t:CalendarItem>
                  </t:Items>
               </m:RootFolder>
            </m:FindItemResponseMessage>
         </m:ResponseMessages>
      </m:FindItemResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: We don't know what's in `outlook/Vinden_kalender_item_antwoord.xml` so there is little we can do.

Comment: Does that mather?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: k, :p
If it was only easy to insert a block of code ...

Comment: seriously, does every line need to have those gd 8 (or even 4) spaces??
Ahn finally worked

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Good, know you just need to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Damn this isn't easy to use for new guys ...

Comment: Almost none of this code is relevant to your problem. You need to produce a [**minimal** working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). That's basic courtesy on this site. You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: No, not good. See our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Those guides tell me nothing about what's important.
I understand that you need the meta around the problem, but I can't give it to you if i don't know what you need ...

Comment: Your question seems to be about line breaks in listings, yet your code contains many lines that have nothing to do with that and doesn't even contain one listing. A good question should usually contain a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), i.e. code that is 1) minimal (contains only what's stricly necessary to explain the problem) and 2) compilable. Your code is neither. Unless you improve your question, you're unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: \lstinputlisting = my listing, the code in the listing is also added, just like the meta data (packages etc);  isn't it your job to create the answer? :s

Comment: @ContradictionOfPro --- No, it isn't anyone's job to create answers. Users of this site provide help voluntarily. Your problems are most likely to be solved if you help the community to help you, by providing a MWE.

Comment: True, but if you don't know how to make a mwe ...

Comment: Then you read the explanation in the link provided by @Jubobs. A MWE contains enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem and nothing more. It's really quite straightforward.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listings package does not break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65743/listings-package-does-not-break)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution which works with the example files you provided at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65839/60451

The code

```
\makeatletter
\def\lst@lettertrue{\let\lst@ifletter\iffalse}
\makeatother
```

will make listings break lines at letter characters.

Comment: Thanks, but where do I have to set this?

Comment: Just somewhere; problem now is that my other lines (who were previously breaked nicely), now got broken somewhere .
Example: <tag>a</tag> got <tag>a</  ENTER tag> now are <tag>a</ta ENTER g>

Comment: Ok. As a quick fix you could declare only "h" as other (breaking) character `\lstinputlisting[... alsoother={h}]{outlook/Vinden_kalender_item_antwoord.xml}`. This will affect other lines, though.

Comment: with only `alsoother={h}', the lines are broken down, but they are ugly as hell, but whatever, it worked TY :D