# hyphenating inline verbatim text at underscore

Tags: verbatim, hyphenation, inline, underscore

I can hyphenate inline verbatim text at a ':'; however, I want to hyphenate inline verbatim text at an underscore '_', but I can not find a solution. The MWE is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\linespread{1.0}\normalsize,
  breaklines=true
}

\geometry{hmargin={6cm,6cm}}

\begin{document}

\lstinline¦hello_world_hello_world_hello_world_hello_world_hello_world_hello_world_hello_world_hello_world¦.

\lstinline¦hello:world:hello:world:hello:world:hello:world:hello:world:hello:world:hello:world:hello:world¦.

\end{document}
```

The typeset result is
[image: MWE typeset result.]

Is there any solution to hyphenate inline verbatim text at '_' without introducing '-', since \texttt macro can hyphenate the above example, but the result is not what I want.

```
\texttt{hello\_world\_hello\_world\_hello\_world\_hello\_world\_hello\_world\_hello\_world\_hello\_world\_hello\_world}.
```

Comment: Looks related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65743/how-can-i-make-the-listings-package-break-lines (same package, although in this case it's inline)

Comment: Welcome to tex.se!  Does the solution given at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140725/15925 help?  I.e. use `listings` and change the class of `_` to `other` rather than `letter`

Comment: Your MWE shows no examples of hyphenation except for the `\texttt` code. I have a feeling that your problem might lie with the `listings` package, not `hyphenat`.

Comment: @user202729: Yes, the message linked is helpful, and the redefinition of \lst@lettertrue leads to break inline verbatim text anywhere if necessary, including underscore ('_') of course.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: The solution linked is helpful too. With \lstset{alsoother={_}}, breaking inline verbatim text at underscore comes true, and this is the original goal I want to achieve, and I am very thankful.

Comment: @PeterWilson: Yes, your feeling is correct, and the problem does lie with the listings package. Under user202729 and Andrew's help, I have got the solution. Besides, I think that I have misused the word 'hyphenating', it should be 'breaking'.